# wkHtmlToPdf css is not applying when generate the PDF

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc-5, wkhtmltopdf

I have a MVC application and want to generate PDF using HTML. In here I use wkHTMLtoPdf exe to do my job.

I call to an action method from client side using jquery. Then it hit to below method.

```
public FileContentResult ExportInvoiceASPDF(string invno)
        {
            try
            {
                Byte[] bytes;                
                var fullUrl = this.Url.Action("pdfCustomerInvoice", "Report", new { invNo = invno }, Request.Url.Scheme);
                bytes = WKHtmlToPdf(fullUrl);

                FileContentResult result = new FileContentResult(bytes, "application/pdf")
                {
                    FileDownloadName = "PriceNotification"
                };
                return File(result.FileContents, "application/pdf");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

In here I called to WKHtmlToPdf function for getting byte stream. (Below code extracted from stackoverflow thread)

```
public byte[] WKHtmlToPdf(string url_input)
        {
            try
            {
                var fileName = " - ";
                var wkhtmlDir = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["wkhtmlDir"];//Directory of wkHtmltopdf exe
                var wkhtml = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["wkhtml"];//wkhtmltopdf exe location
                var p = new Process();

                url = url_input;

                p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                p.StartInfo.FileName = wkhtml;
                p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = wkhtmlDir;

                string switches = "";
                switches += "--print-media-type ";
                switches += "--margin-top 10mm --margin-bottom 10mm --margin-right 10mm --margin-left 10mm ";
                switches += "--page-size Letter ";
                p.StartInfo.Arguments = switches + " " + url + " " + fileName;               
                p.Start();

                //read output
                byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
                byte[] file;
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        int read = p.StandardOutput.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                        if (read <= 0)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                    }
                    file = ms.ToArray();
                }

                // wait or exit
                p.WaitForExit(60000);

                // read the exit code, close process
                int returnCode = p.ExitCode;
                p.Close();

                return returnCode == 0 ? file : null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                // set your exceptions here
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Here I execute the view. (the page which I want to export as PDF)

```
public ActionResult pdfCustomerInvoice(string invNo)
        {
            var inv = _customerInvoiceService.GetCustomerInvoice(invNo);

            InvoiceSummaryReportsVM invRepVM = new InvoiceSummaryReportsVM();

           //My data assigning part going here

            return View(invRepVM);
        }
```

Here is pdfCustomerInvoice html.

```
@model Pro.Web.Models.ViewModels.InvoiceSummaryReportsVM

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">   
</head>
<body>

    <div class="center">
        <h2>Tax Invoice</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InvoiceNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.InvoiceNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InvoiceDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.InvoiceDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AccountNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AccountNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InvoiceStatementPeriod, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.InvoiceStatementPeriod, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OpeningBalance, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.OpeningBalance, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InvoiceTotal, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.InvoiceTotal, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TaxAmount, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TaxAmount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TotalAmountPayable, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TotalAmountPayable, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
    </div>


</body>


</html>
```

The issue is when I execute the code, it is generated the PDF without styling. (All data align to left side.)
But when I call to "pdfCustomerInvoice" method directly, the html comes properly with styling.

**In here I have styling issue. Please give me a direction for fixing this problem.**

Answer (score 2):

It seems that bootstrap won't load then.
Try to link bootstrap css from your file system.

For details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20357784/6589639