# HTML to IMAGE using Python

Tags: python, html, file, type-conversion, file-conversion

Here is a variable **html_str**, it is a string that contains html tags and contents in body.
I am created a **.html** file from this string using the below code in python.

```
html_file = open("filename.html", "w")
html_file.write(html_str)
html_file.close()
```

now i got html file named file "**filename.html**". Now **i want to convert that "filename.html" to a image**, named filename.jpg with the exact contents of the html file.
please help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Render HTML to an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721884/render-html-to-an-image)

Comment: @ThomasSchillaci Actually i want to do it using python, like i created the .html file from the string. i want to apply other operations like cropping to the image file after converting the html file to image.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can do this by using [imgkit](https://pypi.org/project/imgkit/)

```
import imgkit

imgkit.from_file('test.html', 'out.jpg')
```

Or you can also use [htmlcsstoimage](https://docs.htmlcsstoimage.com/example-code/python) Api

```
# pip3 install requests
import requests

HCTI_API_ENDPOINT = "https://hcti.io/v1/image"
HCTI_API_USER_ID = 'your-user-id'
HCTI_API_KEY = 'your-api-key'

data = { 'html': "<div class='box'>Hello, world!</div>",
         'css': ".box { color: white; background-color: #0f79b9; padding: 10px; font-family: Roboto }",
         'google_fonts': "Roboto" }

image = requests.post(url = HCTI_API_ENDPOINT, data = data, auth=(HCTI_API_USER_ID, HCTI_API_KEY))

print("Your image URL is: %s"%image.json()['url'])
# https://hcti.io/v1/image/7ed741b8-f012-431e-8282-7eedb9910b32
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By using the method you described above i got the image version of the html file. But the images in the html file is missing in the .jpg file.

Comment: @Manu__ add `<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-type">
      <meta content="jpg" name="imgkit-format">` in your html string and then try

Comment: In your second method we have to specify the data, right? in my case the data will be a user input so it can vary. This method is not useful in my case. First method is okay. But the converted file, ie, ".jpg" file is missing the images in the html file, please give a solution for that. thanks

Comment: copied <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-type"> <meta content="jpg" name="imgkit-format"> and added it in html string. But the result is still same.

Comment: yes, the image path is correct and i can open the image file. Okay let me check the solution you provided.

Comment: sorry i've deleted my previous comment by mistake [prev-sol](https://dev.to/nodefiend/images-not-showing-up-using-pdfkit-and-wkhtmltopdf-44e8) but you can try this question as well [ques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627310/wkhtmltopdf-not-loading-local-css-and-images)

Comment: Hi, I think i  accidently deleted your first link of the solution, will you please add that too

Comment: The link is there!

Comment: hi sir. i am trying to capture a screenshot from a embeded html (twitter tweets) with imgkit. but the module does not do it right. i guess it dont load the js. its fine when i open it with browser. this is the link to my question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68841037/imgkit-wkhtml2image-cant-load-javascript). help me please

Comment: Does any of the above solutions support full page screenshot? For example, if the page is very long, can any of the above mentioned tools scroll down and capture the entire screen in a single image file?

Comment: Disclaimer:  htmlcsstoimage API is only free up to 50 screnshots per month, and charges (in my opinon) quite high prices if you wish for more.

Answer (score 30):

If you don't want your project to depend on wkhtmltopdf, like other Python modules use, I recommend [html2image](https://pypi.org/project/html2image/).

You can get it using the `pip install html2image` command. A web browser shall also be installed on your machine (Chrome/Chromium or Edge for now).

Once installed, you can take a screenshot of an HTML **string** like so:

```py
from html2image import Html2Image
hti = Html2Image()

html = '<h1> A title </h1> Some text.'
css = 'body {background: red;}'

# screenshot an HTML string (css is optional)
hti.screenshot(html_str=html, css_str=css, save_as='page.png')
```

You can also directly take screenshots of existing HTML **files** or **URLs**:

```py
# screenshot an HTML file
hti.screenshot(
    html_file='page.html', css_file='style.css', save_as='page2.png'
)

# screenshot an URL
hti.screenshot(url='https://www.python.org', save_as='python_org.png')
```

For documentation and more examples, you can check out the [the GitHub page of the project](https://github.com/vgalin/html2image).

Comment: Html2Image is indeed a wrapper around Chrome/Chromium, and has the advantage of generating images that are (most of the time) perfect replicas of what you can see in your own browser, which is not always the case using wkhtmltopdf. As the author of this package, thanks for recommending it, I hope to add support for additional browsers/tools in the future.

Comment: Wish I would have seen this earlier. I'm using this to map a web calendar to an ePaper. All the other tools just displayed a blank page. Thank you both!

Answer (score 6):

Another very useful tool to render HTML sites is the headless Chromium browser.

In javascript you would use the puppeteer api to interact with it but there is a unofficial python port of puppeteer called [pyppeteer](https://pyppeteer.github.io/pyppeteer/)

From my experience with python tools like [imgkit](https://pypi.org/project/imgkit/) the Chromium solution is far more reliable when it comes to loading in external assets like images or iFrames.

To get an image version of the rendered HTML using pyppeteer you simply load the page and then make a full page screenshot:

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch

async def main():
    browser = await launch()
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto('http://example.com')
    await page.screenshot({'path': 'example.png', 'fullPage': 'true'})
    await browser.close()

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Answer (score 2):

check out [HtmlWebShot](https://pypi.org/project/htmlwebshot/0.1.0/)

```py
# pip install htmlwebshot

from htmlwebshot import WebShot
shot = WebShot()
shot.quality = 100

image = shot.create_pic(html="file.html")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from html2image import Html2Image
hti = Html2Image()
with open('./test.html') as f:
    hti.screenshot(f.read(), save_as='out.png')
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, consider sharing a link to the library and some explanation of features or why you suggest it over others. See, the quite identical [answer from ajskateboarder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70910798/5730279) was duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with familiar tool - [selenium](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/take-screenshot-with-selenium-python#:%7E:text=Let%E2%80%99s%20take%20a%20look%20at%20the%20full%20code%20below%20and%20the%20output%20the%20tester%20will%20receive%20as%20the%20screenshot.).
You will just need to put path to the file instead of link:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = ‘path\to\chromedriver.exe’’)
driver.get("file:/path/to/html")
driver.save_screenshot(‘out.png’)
```

Voila, you made an image with few lines of code and without unknown packages