# imgkit (wkhtml2image) cant load javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, screenshot

hi i am trying to convert my html code into an image

this i my python code:

```
def cnv2image():
    options = {
        "--enable-local-file-access": None,
        "--enable-javascript": None,
        "--javascript-delay": 10000,
        "--debug-javascript": None
    }

    imgkit.from_file("tweet_embed.html", "result.pdf", options)
```

and this is my html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0"
          name="viewport">
    <meta content="ie=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-type">
    <meta content="jpg" name="imgkit-format">
    <script async charset="utf-8" src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-theme="dark"><p dir="ltr" lang="en">be honest, do you kiss your dog goodnight?</p>&mdash; ᴘᴀᴠʟᴏᴠ ᴛʜᴇ ᴄᴏʀɢɪ  (@PAVGOD) <a
        href="https://twitter.com/PAVGOD/status/1427841007115116550?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">August 18, 2021</a></blockquote>

</body>
</html>
```

the problem is that when i try to convet html to image js wont get load and i get a screenshot only from html

this is the result that i get:

[image]

this is what i expect:

[image]

Comment: I think the problem is that CSS is not loading. You can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627310/wkhtmltopdf-not-loading-local-css-and-images/20357784) Question.