# How to use .css file with DinkToPdf (wkhtmltopdf) in console application (.Net Core 2.2)?

Tags: c#, css, wkhtmltopdf, dinktopdf

In my console application (.NET Core 2.2) I have a HTML string created with:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(@"<head>");
            sb.Append(@"<link href='"+ AAAA + "' rel='stylesheet'/>");
            sb.Append(@"</head>");
            sb.Append(@"<body>");
            sb.Append(@"<h1>test</h1>");
            sb.Append(@"</body>");
            return sb.ToString();
```

Where `AAAA = Path.Combine(@"file:///C:/Users/asus/Desktop/IT/!!Trials!!/02_APIs/HtmlToPdf_06_CV_Spike/HtmlToPdf/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/styles.css");` is file path, regarding https://github.com/rdvojmoc/DinkToPdf/issues/27#issuecomment-417792667

And it does not work for me. Style sheet does not changes styles on HTML. I also tried `sb.Append(@"<link href='styles.css' rel='stylesheet'/>");` with the same result.

Please note, that `styles.css` file is located in project main folder, also in `(...)Debug/netcoreapp2.2`.

Actually I ran out of ideas and inspirations, from here and SO, how to make my HTML to use CSS in my console application. Is it possible at all? Thank you in advance for your help.

Project tree:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright, I found solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20357784/12603542
Need also add: `file:///` before.

```
private static string CreateHtmlHead()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(@"<head>");
            sb.Append(@"<link href='file:///C:\Users\asus\Desktop\IT\!!Trials!!\02_APIs\HtmlToPdf_06_CV_Spike\HtmlToPdf\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\styles.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen'/>");
            sb.Append(@"</head>");

            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be a good solution. The file path will be different on the server. Will not work for non-windows server