# classes of bootstrap.css not working while i am trying to convert cshtml file to PDF file through WKHTMLTOPDF(pechkin)

Tags: c#, razor, wkhtmltopdf, html-to-pdf, pechkin

I am trying to convert HTML page to pdf using pechkin, I used an internal stylesheet to formate my page, but also want to use some classes of bootstrap.css(external) CSS, in pdf bootstrap classes are not working.

What to do?
Please suggest.

Comment: check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627310/wkhtmltopdf-not-loading-local-css-and-images/20357784#20357784

Comment: @gkulshrestha the same thing is not applicable for CSS according to the link. I tried all solutions. Nothing is working for me.