# Laravel - Outputting a view styled with TailwindCSS as PDF

Tags: laravel, tcpdf, dompdf, tailwind-css, mpdf

I'm trying to make generate a pdf from a view but the styles just won't come out. I've tried using 3 different libraries but the results aren't much different. Am I missing something?

`view`

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Test View</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
  <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
</head>
<body class="font-sans antialiased">

<div class="grid grid-cols-3">
  <div class="bg-red-200 col-span-2 h-screen"></div>
  <div class="bg-blue-200 h-screen">
    <div class="grid grid-cols-8">
      <div class="col-span-7">
        <div class="rounded-t-full w-full h-screen flex items-center justify-center bg-green-600">
          <div class="h-60 w-60 rounded-full bg-blue-500">TEST</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

`appearance`

[image]

---

`dompdf export method`

```
protected function dompdfImplementation()
{
    $dompdf = new Dompdf;
    $dompdf->getOptions()->setChroot(public_path());
    $dompdf->loadHtml(view('view')->render());

    $dompdf->stream('view.pdf', ['Attachment' => false]);
}
```

`dompdf export result`

[image]

---

`mpdf export method`

```
protected function mpdfImplementation()
{
    $mpdf = new Mpdf;
    $mpdf->WriteHTML(view('view')->render());

    $mpdf->output();
}
```

`mpdf export result`

[image]

---

`tcpdf export method`

```
protected function tcpdfImplementation()
{
    $tcpdf = new TCPDF('P', 'mm', 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false);
    $tcpdf->AddPage();
    $tcpdf->writeHTML(view('view')->render());

    $tcpdf->Output('view.pdf', 'I');
}
```

`tcpdf export result`

[image]

---

Is it not possible to export views to pdf without a css inliner?

Am I better off just manually taking a full page screenshot, pasting it into a text document and saving it as a pdf file?

Comment: Have you gone through[Tailwind Docs # Styling for print](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/breakpoints#styling-for-print) or write your own [custom css with @media rule](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_printing.htm)

Comment: scoping the stylesheet to `media="print"` doesn't seem to work either. I think I'm going to look for an inliner.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

After

- trying `barryvdh/laravel-dompdf` instead of `dompdf/dompdf`
- using `media="print"` on my stylesheet
- using TailwindCSS's `print:*` classes
- trying to get `chrome-php` to work to no avail
- trying `barryvdh/excel`'s pdf exports.

Nothing worked so the solution I have reached is a bad one.

1. Open view in firefox.
2. Screenshot whole page (not just visible content).
3. Use the first online PNG to PDF converter I find.

I wish there'd be a less painful way to do this but it doesn't look like it. This bad solution actually works.

Comment: If this is an acceptable solution, why not print the page to PDF directly with, say, PDFCreator?

Comment: That could be a solution but I'm not familiar with that software. It's the first time I've heard of it. ***IF*** it works, I'd consider it an acceptable solution as well.

Answer (score 2):

This package works like a charm (as usual with spatie) :
https://github.com/spatie/browsershot

According to the doc :

> The package can convert a webpage to an image or pdf. The conversion
> is done behind the scenes by Puppeteer which controls a headless
> version of Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If you need support for modern CSS features such as flexbox, which I suppose your Tailwind example utilizes, you'll be better off using headless chrome (or a bit older wkhtmltopdf) to generate the PDF.

An example using `chrome-php/chrome`:

```php
<?php

use HeadlessChromium\BrowserFactory;
use HeadlessChromium\Page;

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$browserFactory = new BrowserFactory();

$browser = $browserFactory->createBrowser([
    'noSandbox' => true,
    'customFlags' => [
        '--proxy-server="direct://"',
        '--proxy-bypass-list=*',
        '--font-render-hinting=none',
    ],
]);

$page = $browser->createPage();

$tempname = '//<path to your HTML over HTTP>';

$page->navigate('file://' . $tempname)
    ->waitForNavigation(Page::NETWORK_IDLE);

$outputPath = __DIR__ . '/output.pdf';

$page->pdf([
    'printBackground' => true,
    'preferCSSPageSize' => true,
    'marginTop' => 0.4,
    'marginBottom' => 0.2,
    'marginLeft' => 0.2,
    'marginRight' => 0.2,
])->saveToFile($outputPath);
```

Use PHP PDF libraries to leverage some of their benefits over browser approach - color handling, pre-print, barcodes support, headers and footers, page numbering, TOCs, etc, but given their support for HTML and CSS, expect a tailored template and stylesheet will most likely be needed.

Of course, the previous paragraph also applies when you are unable to run other software than PHP with your hosting provider.

Comment: This is for a personal project so I don't strictly **need** it to be completely automatic. I'm not sure how to use a headless chrome to achieve what I want. Can you elaborate on that? I just tried wkhtmltopdf and the results were the same. (Just text, no styling)

Comment: https://github.com/chrome-php/headless-chromium-php

Comment: That library looks promising, too bad it's not mantained and just doesn't work.

Comment: There are many others, just pick. Do some work yourself. https://packagist.org/packages/chrome-php/chrome

Comment: I'll try that code out tomorrow, but the last time I tried chrome-php it didn't get past the stage of `createBrowser()`. It threw me errors about the browser not starting and diving into the source code revealed it did not properly support windows .At first glance it does, but for example the first step that library does to create a browser is checking the chrome version... with a command that is meaningless in windows, causing a timeout. Even commenting out that entire section or tripling the timeout didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

This answer might solve the problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36695827/5540654

Basically you need to add a `base` tag in the `head` of your document.

```html
<html>
<head>
...
<base href="http://www.example.com/">
<link href="/assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
...
</head>
```

Worked for me with wkhtmltopdf. Might be a similar issue.