# Fonts generated in HTML & PDF are different in wkhtmltopdf

Tags: php, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

Seems this question has been posted a few times, but posting here again because I couldn't find anything useful for my issue :(

I am using wkhtmltopdf to generate pdf files from HTML views. I have added custom fonts in the site. The rendered HTML view looks great. But the CSS styles aren't applied in the PDF properly.

My CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFont';
    src: url('fonts/MyFont-Light.otf') format('opentype'),
    url('fonts/MyFont-Light.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFont';
    src: url('fonts/MyFont-Regular.otf') format('opentype'),
    url('fonts/MyFont-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}

body {
    font-family: 'MyFont', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}

h1 {
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

HTML View
[image]

PDF View
[image]

Can someone please help me resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627310/wkhtmltopdf-not-loading-local-css-and-images

Comment: Thanks @LarsStegelitz. But here in my case, permission for the CSS file isn't a problem. But the wkhtmltopdf renders a different view compared to the HTML view.

Comment: I meant the answer relating to the base path...